# How to xcode 4 in OSX 10.6.8?

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard

How do I run Xcode on OS X 10.6.8 / Snow Leopard? The Xcode 4 on the App Store is only compatible with 10.7 / Lion and upwards.

Any clue, any hope for goodold 10.6.8 users ?

Comment: The answer below is correct, but that's assuming that you want Xcode 4.2. The latest version is 4.3.1 which is only available for Lion.

Answer (score 6):

If you can log into the iOS Developer Portal, do that and then search for `Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard` and you'll get Xcode 4 for 10.6.8.

Otherwise, go to [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), search for `Xcode` and then you'll find a download for `Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard`.

Comment: Now everything is clear, AFTER I purchased a Developer ID (the one for 100 bucks). 
Just after this. one can see the link to the 4.2 version dmg.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: In `Downloads for Apple Developers`, there is no `Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard`. There is only `Xcode 4.2 for Lion`.

Comment: I just checked it and it is still there, though a few pages in now.  Search for "4C199", which is the build #.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a paid developer, you can download it from apple's online downloads section.

If you're not, you're screwed.